# Count and list specific columns with certain values in R

Tags: r

I have a df with multiple columns of interest (let's say in the example column 3 to 5) which have values that are either 0 or 1. Rows represent individual grid cells. TUsing R, to this df I now want to add a column 'COUNT' that lists per cell **how many** of the columns 3 to 5 have a 1 and then another column 'NAMES' **listing the name** of the columns.

Here's an example df

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c(sample(c(0:1), 10, replace = T)), 
                  var2 = c(sample(c(0:1), 10, replace = T)), 
                  var3 = c(sample(c(0:1), 10, replace = T)),
                  var4 = c(sample(c(0:1), 10, replace = T)),
                  var5 = c(sample(c(0:1), 10, replace = T)),
                  var6 = c(sample(c(0:1), 10, replace = T)))
```

Not sure if this matters, the df in question is of class 'sf' and 'data.frame'. Any ideas how to do this in R would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tidyverse` - create the `COUNT` by `pick`ing the 'var3' to 'var5' columns and get the row wise sum (`rowSums` - as it is binary, 0 values doesn't add), then loop `across` the columns, replace the 1s with column name (`cur_column()`), by default the `TRUE` will be NAs, convert the tibble column to a proper columns with `unnest_wider` and `unite` those `NAMES_` to a single column by pasting while remove the NAs with `na.rm = TRUE`

```
library(dplyr) # version >= 1.1.0
library(tidyr)
library(stringr) 
df %>% 
  mutate(COUNT = rowSums(pick(var3:var5)),
   NAMES = across(var3:var5, ~ case_when(as.logical(.x) ~ cur_column()))) %>% 
  unnest_wider(NAMES, names_sep = "_") %>%
  unite(NAMES, starts_with("NAMES_"), sep = ", ",  na.rm = TRUE)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 × 8
    var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6 COUNT NAMES             
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <chr>             
 1     0     0     1     1     0     0     2 "var3, var4"      
 2     0     0     1     1     1     0     3 "var3, var4, var5"
 3     1     1     1     0     1     1     2 "var3, var5"      
 4     0     1     0     0     0     1     0 ""                
 5     0     0     0     1     0     1     1 "var4"            
 6     0     1     1     0     0     0     1 "var3"            
 7     0     1     0     0     1     1     1 "var5"            
 8     1     1     1     0     1     0     2 "var3, var5"      
 9     0     1     1     1     1     1     3 "var3, var4, var5"
10     0     0     0     1     1     0     2 "var4, var5"
```

Comment: What's the `dplyr >1.1.0` for? Is it `unite()`?

Comment: @SamR it is for `pick`

Comment: Thanks @akrun, this seems very elegant. Is ```pick``` a command exclusive to the newest ```dplyr``` version? I am running an older one as the newest is causing trouble with download and it doesn't recognize ```pick```.

Comment: @Kristina You can replace `pick` with `across` as well.  pick I used for selecting the columns and not applying any function for each column as the `rowSums` is used on the selected data as a whole

Comment: @Kristina Yes, pick is one of the newest additions in dplyr.

Comment: @akrun Wonderful, ```across``` does the trick! Just learned a lot of new things, thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base R method:

```r
cols  <- names(df)[3:5] # "var3" "var4" "var5"

df$COUNT  <- rowSums(df[cols])

df$NAMES  <- apply(df[cols], 1, \(x) {
    col_names  <- paste(
       cols[as.logical(x)], collapse = ";"
    )
    if(col_names == "") col_names  <- NA_character_
    col_names
}
)

#    var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 COUNT          NAMES
# 1     1    1    0    1    0    1     1           var4
# 2     0    1    1    0    0    0     1           var3
# 3     1    1    1    1    1    0     3 var3;var4;var5
# 4     1    1    0    1    0    0     1           var4
# 5     0    0    1    1    1    0     3 var3;var4;var5
# 6     0    1    0    1    1    0     2      var4;var5
# 7     1    1    0    1    1    0     2      var4;var5
# 8     1    0    1    1    0    1     2      var3;var4
# 9     1    0    1    0    0    0     1           var3
# 10    0    0    0    0    1    0     1           var5
```

Alternatively, you could use the same approach with `data.table`:

```r
setDT(df)

df[, COUNT := rowSums(.SD), .SDcols = cols]

df[, 
    NAMES := apply(.SD, 1, \(x) {
        col_names  <- paste(
        cols[as.logical(x)], collapse = ";"
    )
    if(col_names == "") col_names  <- NA_character_
    col_names
    }
    ), .SDcols = cols
]

# same output
```

Edit: I noticed the output was different to @akrun's response so I re-ran it with `set.seed(100)` for reproducibility.